# BitVector performance issues

Tags: python, encryption, bitvector

I need to use bits for operations in a crypto scheme, however, when I transform variables and functions into BitVector(bitstring/int/textstrings="") the result is a very long bitvector, at times of length in the thousands. Now, this slows my encryption and operations on these BitVectors a LOT. How can I overcome this? :(

example of ways I'm using BitVector:

```
    msg = BitVector.BitVector(textstring=message) ^ h1 
    msgxored = msg ^ h1
```

Edit1: For example, `self.bc.encrypt(msgxored, key)` is only ~300 bits, but `encr1 = BitVector.BitVector(textstring = self.bc.encrypt(msgxored, key))` is ~3000 bits!

Comment: Are you sure that you're not mixing bits and bytes? Also, *"performance"* is usually reserved for time-based measurements and not space-based ones. Do you mean time or space?

Comment: i may be.... I mean time! because it is ~3000 bits it takes longer. when done with lesser bits its faster (another encryption scheme for example produces something smaller and is significantly faster)

Answer (score 1):

This is shameless self-advertising but I made https://pypi.python.org/pypi/BytesOp exactly for this.

You could use it like this

```
from BytesOp import op_xor
msg=b"asdf"
h1=b"1234"
msgxored=op_xor(msg,h1)
print(msgxored,op_xor(msgxored,h1))
```

Comment: hey, if it's good it's good ;) 

so is this faster/does it compress bits?

Comment: It operates with native `char` arrays from buffers so there is no compression needed at all. You put in bytes-like objects and you get out a new byte-string. You dont have the fancy object-stuff of BitVector but simplicity (only [175 lines of C](https://github.com/janbrohl/BytesOp/blob/master/bytesop.cpp) )  - while it obviously is not the fastest possible implementation, there is not very much room for optimizations. (I have no benchmarks)

Comment: i'm giving it a try :) will let you know

Comment: there is no special ubuntu package so you should use [pip](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/) and install for the user only (with [--user](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#cmdoption--user) ) - normally it is best to work with [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) when developing anyway

Comment: also to be noted as well that i'm trying to do operations on a GF field of 2^256

Comment: This works on any object that can export simple buffers - bytes, bytearray, str (results may look strange for unicode-strings). Actually not tested with int yet (h1 in my example is a bytestring). What is a GF field?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121760/discussion-between-user65165-and-janbrohl).

Answer (score 0):

Your question does not have much information. Nonetheless, the documentation says that you can set the size of your BitVector.

```
bv = BitVector( intVal = 0, size = 8 )
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: "If the size supplied is smaller than what it takes to create the shortest possible bit vector for intVal, an exception is thrown."

Comment: also, size is only for intVal not for bitstring and textstring

Comment: irrelevant in this case, but how does xor xor (removing xor ) works in BItVector. I couldn't find anything too helpful online